# Java error when adding object list to Jlist

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have problem. I want to add list of created objects to Jlist in other class. I occured many errors. I tried diffrent ways but i stil can't do this. Now i am getting array adress in my GUI but i want names and prize(cena) :( Help please.

**Code in class where i want to add list:**

```
DefaultListModel<String> dlm = new DefaultListModel<String>();

    magazyn.setModel(dlm);
    hurt.addKonsola();
    magazyn.setListData(hurt.konsole.toArray());
    magazyn = new JList(hurt.konsole.toArray());
    //dlm.addElement(hurt.addKonsola());
  //for(String s:hurt.konsole){
     //  dlm.addElement(s);
   // }
```

**And a method in diffrent class:**

```
 public  void addKonsola() {
    Konsola[] konsola = new Konsola[10];
    konsola[0] = new Konsola("PlayStation 2",900,240,"Sony Computer Entertainment",32,100);
    konsola[1] = new Konsola("PlayStation 3",1100,800,"Sony Computer Entertainment",256,320000);
    konsola[2] = new Konsola("PlayStation 4",1250,1400,"Sony Computer Entertainment",8000,500000);
    konsola[3] = new Konsola("Xbox 360",850,450,"Microsoft",512,250000);
    konsola[4] = new Konsola("Xbox One",1150,1200,"Microsoft",8000,500000);
    konsola[5] = new Konsola("Wii U",750,1,"Nintendo",2000,8000);
    //for (int i = 0; i<konsola.length; i++) {
     this.konsole.addAll(Arrays.asList(konsola));

  // }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Can you please be a little bit more specific about the "many errors" you encountered? It makes it easier for people to help you.  Thank you.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Comment: In these code i didnt encountered errors. I got them when typed diffrent code.

Comment: So what is your question then?

Comment: I want to add to list name and prize of Konsola but list show me only arrays adress. in method string toString i cant acces to name :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Konsola should have a `public String toString()` method, returning the String you want to see in JList.

If you set a model to magazyn and then asign another object (new JList) to this variable, the model asignment will have no effect. First assign the List, then set the appropriate model that gives either Strings to the JList or Konsola objects with a toString method.

Try this:

```
public void test(JPanel panel) {
    JList<Konsola> magazyn = new JList<>();
    DefaultListModel<Konsola> dlm = new DefaultListModel<>();
    addKonsola(dlm);
    magazyn.setModel(dlm);

    panel.add(magazyn);
}

public void addKonsola(DefaultListModel<Konsola> model) {
    model.addElement(new Konsola("PlayStation 2", 900, 240, "Sony Computer Entertainment", 32, 100));
    model.addElement(new Konsola("PlayStation 3", 1100, 800, "Sony Computer Entertainment", 256, 320000));
}
```

Of course, you might need to be a little mor specific with the `panel.add(magazyn)`. :-)

My dummy Konsola class looks like this:

```
class Konsola {
    int i = 0;
    String s = null;

    public Konsola(String str, int i, int j, String t, int k, int l) {
        this.s = str;
        this.i = i;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return s + "  " + i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133215/discussion-on-answer-by-upf-java-error-when-adding-object-list-to-jlist).

Comment: I tried many times to do smthg like that dlm2.getElementAt((Konsola)magazyn.getSelectedIndex().cena); but nothing works :/ i dont have idea

Comment: Answer is in the chat